# How do I disable all old meeting reminders (from years ago)

Tags: outlook

Just installed the new Outlook on mac and sync'd up with gmail and yahoo - but it keeps flooding me with meeting reminders from 10 years ago.  How do I disable/delete all these old meeting reminders.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for as an answer: [Office 2016 can't dismiss old notifications (Mac)](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1401570-office-2016-can-t-dismiss-old-notifications-mac)